# Call a java web service method from java client (HTTPPost)

Tags: java, apache, web-services, tomcat7

I want to execute a method define in java web service from a java client. I am using apache tomcat7 to host the web service locally. I am using HttpPost method but I think I am using wrong url. Following is the code for web service:

```
public class Service{
    @POST
    @Path("/getString")
    public String getString(){
        String str = "Hello";
        return str;
    }
}
```

Following is the client code from where I am calling the method:

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/WebService/getString");
        post.setHeadder("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        HttpResponse httpres = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = httpres.getEntity();
        System.out.println("HTTP Response:" + EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    }
}
```

The response of the client is 404 the requested resource "WebService/getString" not found.

Please tell me where should I mention the method name in the client? I have mentioned it in the url "WebService/getString" and have also mentioned the @Path annotation. But why it is not getting the method getString() in web service? Please help...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe because your class is named Service and not WebService?

Comment: I tried but still not getting the response.

Comment: I solved this problem my url was wrong and it was not related to the class name.